# raspbian python script EOF error at startup

Tags: python, linux

I'm trying to set up a pretty simple script to handle playing training videos through vlc on a raspberry pi 3 model B.

I can boot to CLI and run the program fine, but if I add it to rc.local, I get an error at line 60, EOFError: EOF when reading a line
can anyone help me figure this out?

line 60 is `"entry = input("\nVideo to play: ")"` towards the bottom of this exerpt, beyond that point, the code is pretty much the same.

```
import os,subprocess
entry = " "           #variable to hold input on the main menu
entry2 = " "          #variable to hold input on the VERVE menu
looping = False       #variable that decides if videos should loop
lastinput = " "       #variable holds last input on the main menu

while entry != "0":

    if entry == "1":
        lastinput = "Camco Chemical Safety Training"
    elif entry =="2":
        lastinput = "[ENG] Forklift Operator Safety Training"
    elif entry =="3":
        lastinput = "[ESP] Forklift Operator Safety Training"
    elif entry =="4":
        lastinput = "[ENG] The New Hazard Communication Mandate"
    elif entry =="5":
        lastinput = "[ESP] The New Hazard Communication Mandate"
    elif entry =="6":
        lastinput = "Forklift Training (1 of 2)"
    elif entry =="7":
        lastinput = "Forklift Training - Accidents (2 of 2)"

        #open main menu
    os.system("printf '\033c'") #These lines are what wipe out the text from the last screen
    if looping == True:
        print("VIDEOS ARE CURRENTLY LOOPING")
    print("Last video watched: " + lastinput)
    print("\n1. Camco Chemical Safety Training")
    print("2. [ENG] Forklift Operator Safety Training")
    print("3. [ESP] Forklift Operator Safety Training")
    print("4. [ENG] The New Hazard Communication Mandate")
    print("5. [ESP] The New Hazard Communication Mandate")
    print("6. Forklift Training (1 of 2)")
    print("7. Forklift Training - Accidents (2 of 2)")
    print("8. VERST DHL")

    print("\n9. TOGGLE VIDEO LOOP")
    print("0. Close Program")

    print("\nPress 0 at any time during a video to close it.")

    entry = input("\nVideo to play: ")
    if entry == "1":
        #open Camco Chemical Safety Training - if looping is off, play once, if it's on, play forever.
        if looping == False:
            subprocess.call(['vlc', "/home/pi/Desktop/Training/Camco_Training/Camco.mp4", '-Idummy --play-and-exit'])
        elif looping == True:
            subprocess.call(['vlc', "/home/pi/Desktop/Training/Camco_Training/Camco.mp4", '-Idummy --loop'])
        continue
```

Comment: The error doesn't seem to be related to the python script but rather the rc.local, check your syntax there.

Answer (score 1):

Pedro was right, I was able to get it running by changing how I loaded it. It's running just fine now that I removed it from rc.local and added it to .bashrc

booted rpi to cli

```
sudo nano /home/pi/.bashrc
```

last line

```
echo Running at boot
sudo python3 /home/pi/filename.py
```